# Garbage collect a class with a reference to its instance?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

Consider this code snippet:

```python
import gc
from weakref import ref


def leak_class(create_ref):
    class Foo(object):
        # make cycle non-garbage collectable
        def __del__(self):
            pass

    if create_ref:
        # create a strong reference cycle
        Foo.bar = Foo()
    return ref(Foo)


# without reference cycle
r = leak_class(False)
gc.collect()
print r() # prints None

# with reference cycle
r = leak_class(True)
gc.collect()
print r() # prints <class '__main__.Foo'>
```

It creates a reference cycle that cannot be collected, because the referenced instance has a `__del__` method. The cycle is created here:

```
# create a strong reference cycle
Foo.bar = Foo()
```

This is just a proof of concept, the reference could be added by some external code, a descriptor or anything. If that's not clear to you, remember that each objects mantains a reference to its class:

```
  +-------------+             +--------------------+
  |             |  Foo.bar    |                    |
  | Foo (class) +------------>| foo (Foo instance) |
  |             |             |                    |
  +-------------+             +----------+---------+
        ^                                |
        |         foo.__class__          |
        +--------------------------------+
```

If I could guarantee that `Foo.bar` is only accessed from `Foo`, the cycle wouldn't be necessary, as theoretically the instance could hold only a weak reference to its class.

Can you think of a practical way to make this work without a leak?

---

As some are asking why would external code modify a class but can't control its lifecycle, consider this example, similar to the real-life example I was working to:

```
class Descriptor(object):
    def __get__(self, obj, kls=None):
        if obj is None:
            try:
                obj = kls._my_instance
            except AttributeError:
                obj = kls()
                kls._my_instance = obj
        return obj.something()


# usage example #
class Example(object):
    foo = Descriptor()

    def something(self):
        return 100


print Example.foo
```

In this code only `Descriptor` (a [non-data descriptor](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors)) is part of the API I'm implementing. `Example` class is an example of how the descriptor would be used.

Why does the descriptor store a reference to an instance inside the class itself? Basically for caching purposes. `Descriptor` required this contract with the implementor: it would be used in any class assuming that

1. The class has a constructor with no args, that gives an "anonymous instance" (my definition)
2. The class has some behavior-specific methods (`something` here).
3. An instance of the class can stay alive for an undefined amount of time.

It doesn't assume anything about:

1. How long it takes to construct an object
2. Whether the class implements **del** or other magic methods
3. How long the class is expected to live

Moreover the API was designed to avoid any extra load on the class implementor. I could have moved the responsibility for caching the object to the implementor, but I wanted a standard behavior.

There actually is a simple solution to this problem: make the default behavior to cache the instance (like it does in this code) but allow the implementor to override it if they have to implement `__del__`.

Of course this wouldn't be as simple if we assumed that the class state *had* to be preserved between calls.

---

As a starting point, I was coding a "weak object", an implementation of `object` that only kept a weak reference to its class:

```
from weakref import proxy

def make_proxy(strong_kls):
    kls = proxy(strong_kls)
    class WeakObject(object):
        def __getattribute__(self, name):
            try:
                attr = kls.__dict__[name]
            except KeyError:
                raise AttributeError(name)

            try:
                return attr.__get__(self, kls)
            except AttributeError:
                return attr
        def __setattr__(self, name, value):
            # TODO: implement...
            pass
    return WeakObject

Foo.bar = make_proxy(Foo)()
```

It appears to work for a limited number of use cases, but I'd have to reimplement the whole set of `object` methods, and I don't know how to deal with classes that override `__new__`.

Comment: Make what work, exactly?  What are you trying to accomplish?  Why don't you just delete the attribute `Foo.bar` when you are done with the instance?

Comment: Assume the reference is added by external code, that has no control over the lifecycle of the instance. I stumbled upon this problem first while writing a descriptor that could be applied to any class, including `Foo`.

Comment: So, if I understand, in your real-life case you have a local class definition, which at some point goes out of scope, and needs to get freed. But during its lifetime, some **external** code adds attributes to it.  Can you explain how and why?

Comment: @shx2 I added an almost-real-life code example (after the first horizontal break) with an explanation. In my real-life problem I restricted the contract so to avoid this situation, but I'm left with my question.

Answer (score 2):

For your example, why don't you store `_my_instance` in a dict on the descriptor class, rather than on the class holding the descriptor?  You could use a weakref or WeakValueDictionary in that dict, so that when the object disappears the dict will just lose its reference and the descriptor will create a new one on the next access.

Edit: I think you have a misunderstanding about the possibility of collecting the class while the instance lives on.  Methods in Python are stored on the class, not the instance (barring peculiar tricks).  If you have an object `obj` of class `Class`, and you allowed `Class` to be garbage collected while `obj` still exists, then calling a method `obj.meth()` on the object would fail, because the method would have disappeared along with the class.  That is why your only option is to weaken your class->obj reference; even if you could make objects weakly reference their class, all it would do is break the class if the weakness ever "took effect" (i.e., if the class were collected while an instance still existed).

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility I considered. The problem here is that, if the class could be dinamically created (as in the example), the dictionary would become crowded. Maybe with a dead-refs pruning step. Real-life problem? Possibly not, but I don't want to feel limited by an implementation detail of the language. :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed one of the points in your answer. The strong reference to the instance is needed to keep it alive. Otherwise I wouldn't store the reference in the first place.

Comment: @DavideR.: "Crowded"?  Are you saying you're worried the dict will get too big?  By setting `cls._my_instance` all you are doing is setting a key in the class's dict, so there's no getting around that.

Comment: @DavideR.: I guess I haven't really understood your question.  If you insist on keeping the object alive with your reference, then you cannot avoid a reference cycle.  The solution is to *not* keep the object alive.  From your example, I don't see that you need to keep it alive.  If you're just keeping it for caching, letting the object be collected is just invalidating the cache when it dies, which seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @DavideR.: I added a bit more explanation.  Because methods are stored on the class, not the instance, you have no hope of being able to garbage collect the class while the instance is still alive.  The instance *needs* a strong reference to the class to ensure that it can access its methods.

Comment: As I said in the question, the instance is expected to be referenced only as long as the class itself is alive. That explains why a weak reference to the class would be enough (again, look at the descriptor example).

Comment: About weak dictionaries, I was missing that it cleans its members when they die via the weakref callback. Only way I know to install such callbacks is via `weakref`. I will be posting an answer based on this later. Thank you for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is just a special case of the general ref-cycle-with-`__del__` problem.

I don't see anything unusual in the way the cycles are created in your case, which is to say, you should resort to the standard ways of avoiding the general problem.

I think implementing and using a `weak object` would be hard to get right, and you would still need to remember to use it in all places where you define `__del__`.  It doesn't sound like the best approach.

Instead, you should try the following:

1. consider not defining `__del__` in your class (recommended)
2. in classes which define `__del__`, avoid reference cycles (in general, it might be hard/impossible to make sure no cycles are created anywhere in your code. In your case, seems like you want the cycles to exist)
3. explicitly break the cycles, using `del` (if there are appropriate points to do that in your code)
4. scan the `gc.garbage` list, and explicitly break reference cycles (using `del`)

Comment: I'm sorry this is not really an answer to my question, but rather a way to avoid the problem. This still has value for the community, but it's not dealing with the core of the question.

Comment: Anyway I would argue that there is something inherently special in this specific ref-cycle problem. Some ref-cycles can be broken by properly using weak references. This can't be done here as objects apparently must contain a strong reference to their own class.

Comment: @DavideR.: Yes, but why does your descriptor have to give the class a strong reference to the object?  Why don't you store that information weakly, somewhere else (not on the class)?

Comment: @DavidR: Points 3 and 4 in this answer are ways to solve the problem.

Comment: No, because I can't know whenever it is appropriate to `del` (given the example in the question). The only way to know, AFAIK, is via `weakref` callbacks.